# PHP Form to redirect with form results

Tags: php, forms

I have a form that when they submit it, it stores the info in the database. I need to be able to get the form data to come up on redirect page.

It does not need to fetch the database as I would love to do this PHP style. So lets say they enter there name and city. When they click submit it redirects them to a thank-you page with the results from the form on that page.

Comment: I don't see the code sample

Comment: You should be able to use [POST variables](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.post.php) for this. If that doesn't work, [Session variables](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.session.php) are an option as well.

Answer (score 2):

In a form, you have each element have a name, lets say `name="username"`, in the php, yould get the value of this as either a `get`, or a `post` response, depending on the `method` of the form.

**HTML Form**

```
<form action="process.php" method="get">
    <input name="username" type="text"></input>
    <input type="submit" value="Submit"></input>
</form>
```

*or*

```
<form action="process.php" method="post">
    <input name="username" type="text"></input>
    <input type="submit" value="Submit"></input>
</form>
```

**process.php**

```
$someusername = $_GET['username'];

$someusername = $_POST['username'];
```

Comment: So IF I add this code to the process.php when I redirect it using header the info will display on page?

Comment: Petty I know, but for complete example, include a submit button or input.

Comment: Almost there!  Submit type typo.

Comment: Gah! Ill get it eventually! haha

Comment: So the process.php is not styled at all..Is there anyway to grab that info from the process.php and insert it into another php page?

Comment: `process.php` is just what I gave it as an example, the code given can be placed at the top of any `.php` pages, with the `action` changed to fit.

Comment: Yes I know that. Thanks so much for your help..What I am asking is when they click submit it is a boring page with no style..I want to get the data info and bring it into the redirect page..Not just the process.php page. Am I making sense? Sorry if I am not.

Comment: A `.php` page is an `.html` page with a portion that is processed on the server. You can add any styling that you want. Anything that is in a `<php>` tag is processed on the server, anything outside, is sent directly to the client as an `.html`

Comment: @X_JuDah_x:The action attribute to the form will determine where your get / post data will be sent to.  Within the corresponding page, in this example, process.php, you would generate the appropriate html and css to render the page as you see fit.

Comment: okay. I guess I have always redirected it to a html page as to keep the main php separate. I know they cannot get any info from it as it is protected under PHP...So last question.. How do I style the output...I have done everything already by myself. Even connected it to database. This is got me stumped. Thanks again.

Comment: Anything not inside of a `<php>` tag is sent as regular `.html>`, you can embed `<php>` tags inside of any `html` you want. `<head><title><?php>echo $sometitle </php></title></head>`

Answer (score 0):

Form page:

```
<form action="thanks.php" method="post"><input type="text" name="myname" placeholder="Name" /><input type="text" name="mycity" placeholder="City" /><input type="submit" value="submit"></form>
```

PHP Page

```
print "Thanks, ".$_POST['myname']." who lives in ".$_POST['mycity']."!";
```